# Session state SQLServer mode

Tags: sql-server, session-state

From what I read, when session state is in SQLServer mode, it always has to access the DB to get and set Session variables. Is that true or can it use a cache in some situation ? If you have any good articles about how this mode works under the hood, please feel free to share them here. I just can't seem to find anything relevant on Google.

I'm trying to evaluate the risks of using this (performance, reliability, etc.)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**Reliability**: how reliable is your SQL Server instance? Is it clustered? Is it on a remote server?

**Performance**: SQL Server session state is one of the lowest performing session state option.  I assume you are using this in an ASP.NET application and have more than one web server. For each request that requires session state, it will perform at least 1 database query.  If session state is updated during the request, there will be one additional update query executed.  In additional, everything stored in Session State will be read/updated. If you can be careful to limit which pages/resources require session state it may perform ok.

**Alternatives**: If you are only running on one web server, you could use State Server.  If you need to support multiple web servers, you could consider using [App Fabric Caching Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx) provider or [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/).  Both of these will perform better than SQL Server and are potentially more fault tolerant than SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Phil ! Very interesting this App Fabric thing. Didn't know about it.